# How to hide the other activities Phone Call, email, letter and Fax but show the task button only in Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, crm-ribbon-workbench

How to hide the other activities Phone Call, email, letter and Fax but show the task activity button only in Dynamics 365?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do you want to hide? Show some screenshots.

Comment: Navigate to Activity in CRM, on views, the buttons Phone Call, email, letter and Fax are displayed, is there any way to hide those? I already hide this using ribbon workbench but it doesn't work. Please advise.

Comment: Read this: https://www.powerobjects.com/2014/03/24/what-to-do-with-unwanted-activity-types-in-dynamics-crm/

Answer (score 0):

What you require is step 7 in the post below:

https://www.powerobjects.com/2018/05/22/changing-dynamics-365-social-pane-view-activities/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I am not pertaining to social activity pane.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ribbon workbench to hide the unwanted OOB buttons. But this is not true for Activity buttons everywhere. Some flyout menus are uncustomizable.

Add the Activity (activitypointer) in a solution, take a backup, then customize the button the way you want. For ex. Hide. [Read more](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/102796-5-hiding-unhiding-ribbon-elements)

Some other workarounds like friendly alert messages, moving down the order to hide from usability to stay in supported zone. [Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/2014/03/24/what-to-do-with-unwanted-activity-types-in-dynamics-crm/)